# Why am I getting "go: undefined method `on_intel' for #<Resource:xxxxx>" when attempting to install direnv by Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

I tried to install `direnv` by Homebrew, but it kept giving me the following error:

```
go: undefined method 'on_intel' for #<Resource:0x00007ff45598b380>
```

I could install other packages:

```
Error: go: undefined method 'on_intel' for #Resource: 0x00007ff45598b380>
~ brew install direnv
Error: go: undefined method 'on_intel' for #Resource: 0x00007d0840d4010>
~ brew install direnv
Error: go: undefined method 'on_intel' for #Resource: 0x00007fd13f961f00>
~ brew install apib
-=› DownLoading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/libev/manifests/4.33
######################################################################## 100.0%
-› Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/libev/blobs/sha256: de9342ba34cfa8c2f8863a9Zeb7aced34652c302328f80593a449d183c9fele0
-› Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256: de9342ba34cfa8c2f8863a92eb7aced34652c302328f8a593a449d183c9
######################################################################## 100.0%
-› Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/ca-certificates/mani fests/2022-07-19_1
######################################################################## 100.0%
==› Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/ca-certificates/blobs/sha256:9e0df163364a5ae07f3eeZcf39083cd74bcb38eeb5250b706e1c02f878d8d632
-=› Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256:9e0df163364a5ae07f3ee2cf39083cd74bcb38eeb5250b706e1c02f878d
######################################################################## 100.0%
==› Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openssl/1.1/mani fests/1.1.1
######################################################################## 100.0%
=-> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openssl/1.1/blobs/sha256:b4dabe01061f980870548cc1bb5a18b68bcbc9021dc87781ead6e3e29a9abadc
==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256:bAdabe01061f980870548cc1bb5a18b68bcbc9021dc87781ead6e3e29a9
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/apib/manifests/1.2.1
######################################################################## 100.0%
Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/apib/blobs/sha256:d0477956dd662a85a626749dafc2ec674d5fb09ca1627901dabc1f412828846b
-> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256:d0477956dd662a85a626749dafcZec674d5fb09ca1627901dabc1f41282
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Installing dependencies for apib: libev,
ca-certificates and openssl01.1
==> Installing apib dependency: libev
Pouring libev--4.33.monterey.bottle.tar.gz
 /usr/local/Cellar/libev/4.33: 12 files, 483.4KB
```

How do I fix it?

--update at Sep 3, 2022

Today, I tried again to install it and succeeded but I did nothing special to my computer these days...

```
➜  ~ brew install direnv
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> New Formulae
distrobox                           echidna                             kubesess                            libff                               libplacebo                          popeye

You have 8 outdated formulae and 1 outdated cask installed.
You can upgrade them with brew upgrade
or list them with brew outdated.

==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/direnv/manifests/2.32.1
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/direnv/blobs/sha256:68f7b9093d44fdef4210ffeaa8f88e8fa27bef356b4c8b2d4fc7749aab1d2614
==> Downloading from https://pkg-containers.githubusercontent.com/ghcr1/blobs/sha256:68f7b9093d44fdef4210ffeaa8f88e8fa27bef356b4c8b2d4fc7749aab1d2614?se=2022-09-02T23%3A30%3A00Z&sig=tPYifz%2B8fPPVLiUdTmyNsIJ9SuYj3o9GsZ
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring direnv--2.32.1.monterey.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/direnv/2.32.1: 11 files, 9.1MB
==> Running `brew cleanup direnv`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What is the model/year of your Mac?

Comment: @jaume It's iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2017).

Answer (score 1):

go to your homebrew git repo and fetch the newest version then try again

```bash
which brew
# For me /opt/homebrew/bin/brew
# So use this command
git -C /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask fetch
```

Try install go again~

Comment: Thank you. Today, I tried again to install it and succeeded but I did nothing special to my computer these days...

Comment: @hustnzj Actually I did nothing special as well. Perhaps the updates corrupt the env

Answer (score 0):

In my situation

```
    git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask fetch --unshallow
```

afer run the command above ,i got 'undefined method `on_intel' for #Resource:0x00007fbb211fc2d0' error when i run: brew upgrade go

Solution : run `brew update`  and `brew upgrade go` will be success

Answer (score 0):

```
 git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask fetch
```

and run

```
 brew update
 brew upgrade go
```

solved my problem

Comment: How does this differ from the other answers?

Comment: The git command is not --unshallow

Comment: Why does that matter - please explain what it does and why the other answers are wrong if they are. Alkso note other answers say that you need to do more than a git command - Is git sufficient?

Comment: I didn't say the other answers were wrong, but it just so happened that these three commands solved my problem, the other answers didn't fit my mac environment. I guess the root cause is because my brew environment hasn't been updated for a long time.